What is the difference between an `.iso` OS for a network and an `.iso` OS for CD?
Choosing Which .iso to Download:
I want to run Fedora 40 Server edition as the OS for a VM. It will be a development environment for a project I plan to start. I noticed that there were two versions of the x86 64bit .iso, one was a "network version" and the other was a "CD version".

Can someone elaborate on what the difference between the network and CD options are?
And which one should I use to create a new virtual machine on Windows 11 using Hyper-V?


The "network version" is a minimal set that requires internet connection to download everything else. I would choose the full installer just for convenience if doing a VM.

Oh okay good explanation. I would select this as the correct answer if you add it as an answer. And thank you for the clarity, I can't ever remember having to make this choice when downloading a Linux ISO before. This sort of thing has probably become common due to people mostly using a cloud computing to launch and run their applications.

The "network" versions assume that you have a network available during installation and that it is fast enough for you to download needed packages on the fly. It assumes that you know you have a network adaptor that is compatible with the operating system you are installing and that it can be brought up and used to download packages. As a result it will contain only enough on the install media to run and launch the installer. It most likely will not contain packages on the install media.
The "CD" version assumes you may not have a network available, or for whatever reason do not wish to use it and so will contain a large selection of default packages on the install media.
If your network is slow or you have a fast network in an alternative location then you may prefer the CD version, but you will have potentially downloaded a large number of packages you don't need or want. If your network is fast or you only need a minimal amount of packages you can use the Network media as it will save you downloading a lot of unnecessary packages.
As the Network media is getting packages from download servers straight away then it may be more up to date than the CD version which could be an older snapshot of packages, though it is likely you can update them all from within the environment once installed, or even during installation if it can connect to the internet.
The end result is going to be (nearly) the same between install media.
Choose whichever version suits you.
Do you have the internet available and want a faster initial download but can deal with a slower install while it downloads packages? Get the network version.
Do you want everything downloaded before you start for a faster install at the cost of downloading a lot of stuff you may not need? Use the CD version.
